# How To Set [Authorize] attribute to only a group of ActionResults Within The Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5.2

Suppose I have a Controller with 100's of ActionResult's Like Below

```
public class BasicController : Controller
{ 
    public ActionResult Apple1()
    {
    }
    public ActionResult Apple2()
    {
    }
            .
            .
            .
    public ActionResult Apple100()
    {
    }



    public ActionResult Mango1()
    {
    }
    public ActionResult Mango2()
    {
    }
             .
             .
             .
    public ActionResult Mango100()
    {
    }
}
```

Now How can I set [Authorize(Role="AppleAdmin")] to only Apple named methods and [Authorize(Role="MangoAdmin")] Mango named methods?

I know we can do it by decorating each ActionResult individually. But What I want to know is, Is there a way to `set the Authorize to a Group` of ActionResults once. So that makes me use the Authorize attribute only twice in my above scenario.

Comment: Using attributes may not be the best solution here (controller with hundreds of actions, which is odd in any case), perhaps you could setup a global action filter and have it do some logic based upon convention.

Comment: Thing is Its a Report Controller and there are around 30+ reports. I need to restrict only few for a type of role and all for admin. How do i go about It?
 I right now have a solution to have a 1 common landing method for a particular type of report and authorizing this will solve it. But just wanted to know if there is anything like group authorization

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to separate Apple & Mango into two separate controllers and just decorate the controller?

Comment: Yes that would be the solution. So you sure that there is nothing like group autorization?

Comment: @jumpingcode what if I am not allowed to separate them? Due to Coding convention followed by the team

Comment: @Reddy I mean you could write a custom authorisation attribute that uses Reflection to check if the method name contains Apple or Mango and then  check the user is allowed...but that's a hack, the solution is to separate them.

Comment: @Reddy I mean...what sort of coding convention is preventing clean code?

Comment: @jumpingcode not really a coding convention. All I wanted to know is what if we cant clean up the controller?? just a question.. :)

Comment: @Reddy I was just interested was all :)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming cleaning up the controller isn't an option, the only answer I can think of is a custom `AuthorizeAttribute` on the controller.
If you override the `OnAuthorization` method you can inspect the `AuthorizationContext` argument for the action name (`filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName`) and set `filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult` if it fails your logic.

Something like

```
public class AppleMangoAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttibute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName.Contains("Apple") /*&& some other failing logic*/)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
        }
        else if (/*same for mango*/)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
        }
    }
}
```

Then

```
[AppleMangoAttribute]
public class BasicController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Apple1() 
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, But My question was more towards different methods (nothing to do with similar start name, It was just for easy understanding of the OP) to be grouped under same Authorization attribute at once. This solution sure does resolve the problem posted. But I guess I should have put across different method names. So how can this be solved if the methods names are not similar

Comment: That's fair enough. Still, take a look at what's available with the `AuthorizationContext`, you may yet be able to filter in the way you require.

Answer (score 1):

I would separate the controller in 2 classes and just modify the routing to access the 2 controllers via the same route.

Note: Personally I haven't tested if this solution will crash the routing but it's the best I could come up with:

```
    [Authorize(Role="AppleAdmin")]
    [Route("BasicController")]
    public class BasicControllerApple : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Apple1() 
        {
        }
    }

    [Authorize(Role="MangoAdmin")]
    [Route("BasicController")]
    public partial class BasicControllerMango : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Mango1() 
        {
        }
    }
```